# Should I store users friend list on device or server?

Tags: android, iphone

I am making an application based on location services. I want to know best practices for storing users friend list. If friends list is stored on server then if user don't have internet connection he will not be able to see the friends list. On the other hand if friends list is stored on device (and there is no internet connection), list might be not up to date.
I understand it is not a programming question but would like to know what will be the better practice.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about storing it in both places? Canonical server copy, and local cache?

Comment: If you are experienced mobile app developer then you might be knowing about **Syncing** functionality.

Comment: @Thilo,  thanks for the speedy reply and suggestion..!!

Comment: @PareshMayani, this is first time I am doing this part.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, iCloud has a very extensive API allowing you to store local copies and detect alterations to local and remote files to easily set up syncing:

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php)

Not sure how to implement a similar system on Android however.

Answer (score 1):

Android and Google gives you a free Backup service which allows you to store your application data on a remote Google server and do restores as required. Android provides a nice API for making it all happen very easily so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.
So I would go for a solution where you would store data at the client side but do scheduled backups

For more info take a look at [Android Data Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)